# How to write the row equivalent matrices in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, accents

I am trying the process performing on a matrix to reduce it to echelon and reduced echelon form as shown in figure
I search a lot and tried like $^R\sim$. I am trying to write the symbol used for row equivalence between two matrices but can not write.

[image]

Comment: `\stackrel{\scriptscriptstyle R}{\sim}` should work (IMO the R on the image is why to large so I made it smaller)

Comment: Please clarify your typesetting objective. Is to write the letter `R` with a tilde symbol underneath it?

Comment: @Mico Yes sir! R with a tilde underneath

Comment: @NoorAslam - Does the output of `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{accents} \begin{document} $\underaccent{\tilde}{R}$ \end{document}` meet your needs?

Comment: @Mico Not running sir getting some error

Comment: And what would that "some error" be? (Sorry, my divination skills are worthless.)

Comment: @Mico I check may be the package \usepackage{accent} is absent

Comment: @NoorAslam -- Does daleif's suggestion -- `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} $\stackrel{R}{\sim}$ or $\stackrel{\scriptscriptstyle R}{\sim}$ \end{document}` -- meet your needs?

Comment: @Mico Yes sir but in that case $R$ looks very small

Comment: I think you can do something about that using `\limits`, but I forgot how to use it...

Comment: @Mico Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...tstyle R}{\sim}$ $\underaccent$${\tilde}

Comment: It is definitely **not** an `R` with a `\sim` **under** it. It is a `\sim` with an `R` above it. I made the `R` smaller because on the image the `R` takes all the attention, but it is just a marker. As far as I remember the `R` just means that this equivalence is made using a **row** operation, and this the `\sim` is the important part not the size of the `R`.

Comment: @daleif Everybody is entitled to use their own preferred notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for example I have created the last matrix of your image with edit by *very good user @egreg*:

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[\mathrel{\underset{\sim}{R}}\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix} 
\\
\,\text{by }\,\mathsf{R}_{1}+\mathsf{R}_{3}\text{ and }\,\mathsf{R}_{2}-\mathsf{2R}_{3}\\
\\
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be `\mathrel{\underset{\sim}{R}}`